# @media screen not rendering for mobile

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm using the media screen query in my css but the problem is that it's not rendering for mobile. It renders for computer screen sizes but when it comes to mobile devices it doesn't work.

Here is my css

```
.featured-post-image{
position:absolute;
left:0;
right:0;
width:100% !important;
height:100%;
max-height:700px !important;
}

.wrap{
position:relative;
padding-top:37em;
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 320px) 
and (max-device-width: 480px)

.wrap{
padding-top: 5em !important;
}

}
```

With this in my header

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

What I am trying to do is change the padding on `.wrap` and it's not working. Can anyone tell me why it's not working?

Comment: where r html code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    .wrap { padding-top: 5em !important; }
}
```

You forgot the curly braces in @media.

Comment: I dind't forget them they are there

Answer (score 0):

For Mobile Responsive you have add these things :

## In Header :

```
// Browser rendering properly 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 

// Select device view port width
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

// for device touch gesture 
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
```

## In CSS :

```
@media screen and (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1200px){

    // css goes here
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px){

   // css goes here 
}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){

   // css goes here
}
```